# Is the commutator subgroup of the commutator subgroup still a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is any group, let $G_1:=[G,G]$ and $G_2:=[G_1,G_1]$. Is it true that $G_2$ is still a normal subgroup of $G$ or are there exceptions? I've tried coming up with a homomorphism with kernel $G_2$, but I couldn't really get anything started. Does anyone know if this is true or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because the commutator subgroup is characteristic, see here:

[Commutator subgroup $G'$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768364/commutator-subgroup-g-is-a-characteristic-subgroup-of-g)

[If $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and $M$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N$, then $M$ is a normal subgroup of G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647058/if-n-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-a-group-g-and-m-is-a-characteristic-subgroup/647066)

Comment: I see, thank you very much!